# How to download xls or xlsx file in angular6 (Blob API response)

Tags: angular6, blob, xlsx

I was trying to download ***XLSX*** file received as a ***blob*** in API response but it was received as ***HttpErrorResponse***

This was due to change in request structure of angular from angular5.

I had tried request which was responded with HttpErrorReponse object as follows :

```
myBlobRequest():Observable<any>{
return this.http.get(url, { responseType: 'blob'})
            .map((response: Response) => {
                return response;
            })
            .catch((res: Response) => {
                // handleError(response)
            });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**Following solution worked for me**. As it was giving json parse error in *HttpErrorResponse*

**Solution** :

`{ responseType: 'blob'} should be replaced with { responseType: 'blob' as 'json'}`

**Request :**

**GET** Method :

```
myBlobRequest():Observable<any>{
return this.http.get(url, { responseType: 'blob' as 'json' })
            .map((response: Response) => {
                return response;
            })
            .catch((res: Response) => {
                // handleError(response)
            });
}
```

**Response :**

**Handle in subscriber function :**

- With File Saver library:

```
this.serviceObj.myBlobRequest.subscribe((blobResponse)=>{
            var blob = new Blob([resp], { type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats- 
                       officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;' });
            FileSaver.saveAs(blob, "test.xlsx");
});
```

- Without File Saver library:

```
this.serviceObj.myBlobRequest.subscribe((blobResponse)=>{
            var blob = new Blob([resp], { type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats- 
                       officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;' });
            // Download File without FileSaver
            const downloadUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            var link = document.createElement('a');
            link.href = downloadUrl;
            link.download = "test.xlsx";
            document.body.appendChild(link);
            link.click();
            document.body.removeChild(link);

});
```

Comment: That makes no sense. Adding `as 'json'` is just lying to the compiler about which overload will get called, and your map callback is totally pointless anyway. If you want to get the response object in HttpClient, see https://angular.io/guide/http#reading-the-full-response.

Comment: @jonrsharpe , Thank you for suggestion. This solution worked for me because in my case, HttpErrorResponse object was received and in error.error >> json parse error was shown.